# Python string concatenation

Tags: python, html

I'm wondering what the difference is between two statements. I want to print a variable in a `<p>` html tag. Both statements do the same thing but one give me an error.

The first statement that works:

```
out += "</p><p style=""background-color:white"">"
out += uSetMinF
out += "</p><p>"
```

The second one that doesn't work:

```
out += "<p style=""background-color:white"">"uSetMinF"</p>"
```

Here's the error that I get:

```
out += "<p style=""background-color:white"">"uSetMinF"</p>"
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Although the first statement works, I'd rather use the second one because it saves time and it's a little less code. I know it's semantics but I'm also curious. If someone knows the answer please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate literal strings and variables you have to use the `+` operator:

```
out += "<p style=""background-color:white"">" + uSetMinF + "</p>"
```

This is equivalent to your first example, but probably incorrect for what you want. The resulting string will be the following:

```
<p style=background-color:white>whatever uSetMinF is</p>
```

There are no quotes around the `style` value. This is because Python treats

```
"<p style=""background-color:white"">"
```

as if it was

```
"<p style=" "background-color:white" ">"
```

i.e. three separate string literals. In comparison to variables, Python concatenates consecutive string literals without the need of the `+` operator.

If you want to preserve the quotes in your quoted string, you have two options:

1. Escape the inner quotes:

   `out += "<p style=\"background-color:white\">" + uSetMinF + "</p>"`
2. Mix single- and double-quotes:

   `out += '<p style="background-color:white">' + uSetMinF + '</p>'`

Answer (score 0):

The quotation are used to enclosure the strings, use backslash to escape them or use single quotation mark: ' as the first AND last

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is a bit old but there is a better solution:

you can use the .format() or the %s. e.g

```
out += '<p style="background-color:white">%s</p>' % str(uSetMinF)
```

or

```
out += '<p style="background-color:white">{0}</p>'.format(uSetMinF)
```